# get the log author in jenkins build

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I have Jenkins with the git plugin.  I want to the a author that appears in the git log for a particular commit in the MANIFEST.MF file.  I have the maven-jar-plugin to do this, and I also send in the build number and hash.

The Jenkins build command looks like this:

```
clean install -DskipTests -Dbuild.number=${BUILD_NUMBER} -Dbuild.revision=${GIT_COMMIT} -Dbuild.author=${GIT_AUTHOR_NAME}
```

Now the BUILD_NUMBER and GIT_COMMIT are working just fine,  but the author name is NULL.

I set a behavior to use commit author in changelog,  but that did not work.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve git committer/author by parsing the `GIT_COMMIT` Env variable.

```
GIT_AUTHOR=$(git --no-pager show -s --format='%an' $GIT_COMMIT)
```

Comment: Now where do I set this in Jenkins?  I tried it as part of the build command line,  but that is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

let's get their emails :

```
git shortlog -sen | awk -F"[<>]" '{print $2}'
```